# How to access Github Wiki Branches

Tags: github, github-pages

I am able to access Github Wiki pages directly using the below URL:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Siminov/android-core/Preface.md

But if I create a branch of master Github Wiki then how to access those pages?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Non-`master` branches of GitHub wikis are not available through the web interface](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/):

> Once you have cloned the wiki, you can add new files, edit existing ones, and commit your changes. You and your collaborators can create branches when working on wikis, but only changes pushed to the `master` branch will be made live and available to your readers.

The only way to access them is via the wiki repository using whatever software you prefer for working with Git.